# Django ValidationError not being raised when trying to login using an email address that does't exist

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a simple login page where the user will input the email address and password, and django will log him/her. If not, then show "Email not found" Validation error above the form. The problem I am experiencing is that if the email address is found in the database then the user will be logged in but, if then user is not then it wont show the validation error and ultimately move to 'autheticate' function statement where since the user is 'None' will show error. I have put print statements both in my View class and clean_email function, and it can be seen from the output that the clean_email function is called and it also executes the statement in the ValidationError part.

LoginView:

```
class LoginView(View):
template_name = None  # gets overriden in urls.py

def get(self, request, ut):
    form = LoginForm()
    ctx = {
            'form' : form,
            'ut' : ut,
    }
    
    return render(request, self.template_name, context=ctx)

def post(self, request, ut):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    print("the errors are", form.errors")
    print("the form is valid:",form.is_valid())
    if not form.is_valid() :
        ctx = {
            'form' : form,
            'ut': ut,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

    user = authenticate(request, email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'], user_type=ut)
    login(request, user)
    return redirect(reverse('home:index'))
```

LoginForm:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput)
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

def clean_email(self):
    original_email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    print(original_email)
    qs = User.objects.filter(email=original_email)
    print(qs)
    print(qs.exists())
    if not qs.exists():
        print("entered error box")
        return forms.ValidationError("email not found")
    return original_email
```

Flow:

1. As soon as the form is submitted, the 'clean_email' function in 'LoginForm' is called and it prints out the 'original_email' which is correct.
2. Then, email is checked with the database, whether it exists or not and 'qs' is printed
3. It prints whether 'qs' exists or not.
4. The If condition is checked and it enters the block if its true (which in this case is true) and executes the print statement in the block. The function return the Validation error.
5. The 'LoginView' is called and 'form.error' is referenced, which comes out to be NULL, (the validation error in the LoginForm is present).
6. 'is_valid' function is called (which in this case outputs True), as a result if condition becomes false and it moves to authenticate part, and then Login. Since, User is Null, it throws and error.

I am confused as to why no errors are shown in the 'form.error' dictionary when I have returned a ValidationError and why is 'is_valid' outputing true? should't it be False?

Output:

```
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wds2N.png][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntaxis error, maybe can be that:

```
def post(self, request, ut):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    print("the errors are", form.errors) # In this line, you have extra quotes at the end
```